# Sending Email to Gmail's SMTP server using TLS and Plain Authentication

Tags: email, ssl, authentication, smtp, gmail

I have a situation. I want to connect to gmail smtp server and send Email from my gmail account. as gmail smtp server uses PLAIN authentication and TLS. I connect to gmail smtp server. and server response is as follow.

> 220 mx.google.com ESMTP n21sm810716wed.43

then I send it "AUTH PLAIN" and send "EHLO" command. The server responses are as follow:

> ```
> 503 5.5.1 EHLO/HELO first. n21sm810716wed.43
> ```

I then sent it "EHLO" command again and response is:

> 250-mx.google.com at your service, [203.99.179.10]

after this whatever I give it. It prints a sequence of line and Exit. The sequence of responses which it gives are;

> 250-SIZE 35882577
>
> 250-8BITMIME
>
> 250-STARTTLS
>
> 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

what should I give it so that it let me login and send me Email? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

#### See also

> [Using SMTP, Gmail, and STARTTLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281669/using-smtp-gmail-and-starttls)

Comment: You tagged your question with "c", but there are no references to C code. Are you writing a C program to connect to a SMTP server? Are you using any library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not use STARTTLS unless we have a secure connection with the server. simple SMTP library and telnet do not support STARTTLS. For this I had to use GNUTLS which performs handshaking with the server and exchange certificate to establish a secure connection. After that I send STARTTLS and it works fine. Hope this helps other facing similar problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are facing 3 problems:

First, you are **not reading entire response** of EHLO command.

This command has **multi-line** response:

```
250-mx.google.com at your service, [203.99.179.10] 
250-SIZE 35882577 
250-8BITMIME 
250-STARTTLS 
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
```

Note the **space** after last 250 code - it means that this is the last response line.

Second: 
EHLO should be the **first** command you send.

Third:
Gmail does not allow to log-in without using SSL, either implicit (on 465 port) or explicit (STARTTLS command)

Comment: I am reading the entire response of Ehlo command. the Ehlo is the first command that I am sending. after these responses I sent it STARTTLS and server response "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS" but whatever I sent after this server quit. I have no idea Where I am making mistake or missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should issue the STARTTLS command after the given response. Here is an SMTP conversation example, obtained with `netcat` on `smtp.gmail.com` on port 587:

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP z83sm46627weq.20
EHLO localhost
250-mx.google.com at your service, [109.114.60.32]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

Comment: I issued STARTTLS command and get response "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS". But whatever I enter after that the server sent me the quit reply. Why is that?? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ali Do you start to use SSL after you issue STARTTLS command?

Comment: @Pawel Lesnikowski I did not understand what is mean by "use SSL". after STARTTLS I simply continue sending data on the same socket without and modification of step. Can you please explain it?

Comment: It means starting the TLS handshake. After that, all data sent and received is encrypted: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security.

After STARTTLS, you have to reissue the EHLO command, and then proceed authenticating with the AUTH command: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4954